# IOS - How do I block open one app from another app programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webview, openurl

I'm trying to watch youtube videos in my app's UIWebView itself. Whenever I tap on any of the webpage youtube link, it will automatically redirect into youtube application but youtube's app is also installed in my device. How can I block opening of one app from another app programmatically.

Comment: did u implement the web view delegate methods ? You can return NO, when the UIWebViewNavigationType is a UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37240425/5622566 have you tried this?

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `UIWebview`

Add following delegate method in your viewcontroller. And assign `webview.delegate = self`

```
extension YourVC:UIWebViewDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        if navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationType.linkClicked {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

If you are using `WKWebview`,

Add following delegate method in your viewcontroller. And assign `webView.navigationDelegate = self`

```
extension YourVC:WKNavigationDelegate{
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        if navigationAction.navigationType == .linkActivated {
            decisionHandler(.cancel);
            return;
        }
        decisionHandler(.allow);
    }
}
```