# URL scheme in iOS with WebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, url-scheme

I'm developing an iOS application in which I want to provide users with a payment gateway, which is a web page. I'm showing this web page in a WebView.
The payment gateway accepts 2 URL params - success and failure URL, which are the URLs users is redirected to after completing purchase. Redirect is done via JavaScript `location.href` property and works properly in desktop browser and Android app.

I've set the URLs to let's say `tft://redirect/success?id=123` resp. `tft://redirect/failure?id=123`

I want my app to handle this redirect and show Success or Failure message to user.

I followed many tutorials including [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/defining_a_custom_url_scheme_for_your_app).
First of all I'm not sure why Apple docs show scheme without slashes (`myphotoapp:` instead of `myphotoapp://` - does it make a real difference?)

I've registered custom scheme `tft` and implemented the `func application(..)` function according to the docs.

Now when the redirect should happen, nothing really happens, the `func application` is not called at all.

I started development with iOS 12 and recently switched deployment target to 13.5, however, the project structure didn't change (scene delegate missing - is it an issue?).

Can you please give me any direction?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your URL scheme should be unique to your application, I wouldn't recommend using "app".  The URL scheme should be included in the PLIST without colon or slashes.  Showing screenshots of how you've configured the PLIST, your app delegate code, as well as the JS that sets window.location would be helpful to diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/37240425/9046249 custom scheme behaves somewhat wierd. When I switched the scheme to `http` or `https` it works like a charm.