# Swift 5 Disable Redirection from WKWebView to different Apps

Tags: ios, swift, webview, wkwebview

I have a `WKWebView` inside my app. The problem is that when for example going on **https://stockx.com/de-de** and the user has the **StockX** app, the user is redirected to the app.
Is there any way to disable this redirection in genreal for my `webView`? I couldn't find anything on this... Not too sure if you need code but here is my `webView`:

```
lazy var webView: WKWebView = {
    let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    webView.uiDelegate = self
    webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return webView
}()
```

Apparently there is this function for an older Swift version:

```
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
    print("webView:\(webView) decidePolicyForNavigationAction:\(navigationAction) decisionHandler:\(decisionHandler)")

    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
    let url = navigationAction.request.URL
    let myScheme: NSString = "https"
    if (url!.scheme == myScheme) && app.canOpenURL(url!) {
        print("redirect detected..")
        // intercepting redirect, do whatever you want
        app.openURL(url!) // open the original url
        decisionHandler(.Cancel)
        return
    }

    decisionHandler(.Allow)
}
```

But this is no longer working in **Swift 5**. Any idea how to to this in Swift 5?

Answer (score -1):

So what is happening here it's web app initializing universal link. What you can theoretically do to block this:

Reference to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37240425/11555781)

```swift
func webView(webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyForNavigationAction navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void)) {
        print("webView:\(webView) decidePolicyForNavigationAction:\(navigationAction) decisionHandler:\(decisionHandler)")

        let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        let url = navigationAction.request.URL
        let myScheme: NSString = "https"
        if (url!.scheme == myScheme) && app.canOpenURL(url!) {
            print("redirect detected..")
            // intercepting redirect, do whatever you want
            app.openURL(url!) // open the original url
            decisionHandler(.Cancel)
            return
        }

        decisionHandler(.Allow)
    }
```